# creating trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
create trigger trig_image
on ImageGallery
After insert
as begin
declare @id int;
@id=1; //line#6
update ImageGallery set img_id='img'+@id;
@id=@id+1; //line#8
end
go
```

I am creating trigger for an `image` table with fields `img_id varchar(50),image content`
Now whenever insert happens, I want to auto increment this `img_id` column but it's showing me error at line no. 6 and 8.

Comment: What database engine are you using?  This looks to be some sort of hybrid of Oracle and SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You should user `SET`

```
create trigger trig_image
on ImageGallery
After insert
as begin
declare @id int;
SET @id = 1;
update ImageGallery set img_id='img'+@id;
SET @id=@id+1;
end
go
```

I am a MySQL guy, but you may try using `SET` as updated above.

Comment: @shweta what database are you using?

Comment: @shweta I have updated the answer. You see line #6 and #8 has changed.